# Separar resultado em planilhas diferentes

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, xls

Tenho um problema no qual tenho que pegar todas as minhas informações (informação de cada célula da planilha), faze-las passar por uma condição e para cada resultado da condição escrever em um nova planilha de um novo arquivo.

Por exemplo, tenho o arquivo teste.xls que contém uma planilha e todas as informações.
Todos os valores desta planilha passarão por 3 condições, sendo que essas condições as separam em Nome, Idade e Sexo. Ou seja todas os valores da minha planilha serão separados em Nome, Idade e Sexo.
A grande questão é, criar um novo arquivo com 3 planilhas sendo que cada uma terá o nome Nome, Idade e Sexo e cada resultado irá apra sua determinada planilha.

Meu código está pronto, ele traz todo o resultado que quero no terminal, porém eu não sei por onde começar para separar cada resultado de cada condição para sua determinada planilha. Eu sei da biblioteca `xlwt`, porém estou com dificuldade sobre como separar as os resultados nas planilhas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando que você está procurando é `add_sheet`.

Este código cria um arquivo com três planilhas e escreve em cada uma. Deve ser adaptável ao seu caso:

```
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Nome")
sheet2 = book.add_sheet("Idade")
sheet3 = book.add_sheet("Sexo")

sheet1.write(0, 0, "Celula 1 da Planilha 1")
sheet2.write(0, 0, "Celula 1 da Planilha 2")
sheet3.write(0, 0, "Celula 1 da planilha 3")

book.save("trial.xls")
```

Adaptado [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13437727/174365) do StackOverflow em inglês.

Comment: Oi, é exatamente isso que eu quero fazer. Porém os resultados não são valores fixos. Primeiramente eu leio os valores e depois preciso escrever, é exatamente isso que você me passou. As planilhas são criadas, mas os valores não são repassados para as planilhas. Por exemplo, eu leio toda a minha coluna Nome, Idade e Sexo, e elas são listadas no terminal, está perfeito, agora quando faço isso que você me passou, só é criado as planilhas, cada uma com o nome que definimos, porém sem os valores.

Comment: Consegui!Obrigada!